# Auto parallelization of simple DO loop - memory reference too complex

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, fortran90

I am using Absoft pro Fortran and I have a piece of code as follows:

```
program test1

INTEGER :: q, CAPQ, ingrid(1:6), outgrid(1:10)

ingrid = (/1,2,3,4,5,6/)
outgrid = 0
CAPQ = 6

DO q=1,CAPQ
      outgrid(q) = ingrid(q)
ENDDO

END
```

However, when I build it it wont auto parallelize because:

> The loop with the index variable Q cannot be parallelized because it contains an indirect memory reference that is too complex to be analyzed successfully.

And yet this is a very simple memory access, I am simply calling the number from array and placing it into another. It should not matter what order it occurs in, and hence can be parallelized.

Comment: A compiler must avoid parallelization with threads storing within 128 bytes of each other as that will incur false sharing.

Comment: is there a way to work around it, so as to not prohibit parallelization?

Comment: I removed the reference to OpenMP: OpenMP does not cover auto-parallelization, and I can't find a reference that absoft pro uses OpenMP for it's auto-parallelization. Please clarify if you think it is really related to OpenMP.

Comment: @tim18 could you explain a little more what you mean? and how to avoid that. Much appreciated.

Comment: If one intends to use OpenMP then some OpenMP directives are needed. I would start with USE OMP after propgram and before the missing implicit none.

Comment: If the compiler has any criteria about problem size for parallel execution that would prevent it.  The case may not even benefit from auto-vectorization which might be higher priority.

Comment: @Holmz Most programs don't need `use omp_lib` (not `use omp`) at the beginning. My 40kLOC code has less then 10 occurrences of it and none at the start of the main program.

Comment: Your screenshot shows nothing. OpenMP is on, but you are not using it. The warning comes from autoparallelization, not OpenMP.

Comment: OMP was originally in the code, so the compiler switch makes sense historically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Absoft Fortran, but I can tell I have yet to find a compiler that does a great job concerning auto-parallelization. It is a difficult task anyway, and I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a compiler able to parallelize the code even close to what you can achieve if you do it yourself. I would strongly recommend you consider parallelizing your code using OpenMP (or whatever parallelization lib you may choose). It's not difficult and it really pays off, especially if you paralellize the "bottlenecks" of your code. In this particular example, the code can be easily paralellized as

```
program test1
use omp_lib
implicit none

integer :: q, CAPQ, ingrid(1:6), outgrid(1:6)

ingrid=(/1,2,3,4,5,6/)
outgrid=0
CAPQ=6

!$omp parallel do private(q)
do q=1,CAPQ
  outgrid(q)=ingrid(q)
  print "(2(a,i0))","q=",q," processed by thread ",omp_get_thread_num()
end do
!$omp end parallel do

end program test1
```

Note that I added a `print` statement to verify that the executable is indeed running the do-loop in parallel. Compile and run the example with and without the two `!#omp` statements to see the difference. With parallelization enabled, you should see something like

```
q=6 processed by thread 5
q=4 processed by thread 3
q=5 processed by thread 4
q=2 processed by thread 1
q=3 processed by thread 2
q=1 processed by thread 0
```

and thread should be zero everywhere, if parallelization is disabled.

The above example is in gfortran, and must be compiled with the -fopenmp directive.
Depending on the compiler you use, the statement `use omp_lib` might need to be replaced with something similar, and the compiler directive might also be slightly different. According to the Absoft Pro Fortran User's Guide I found online, the compiler directive is -openmp. The User's Guide also mentions options for "aggressive OpenMP" parallelization, which are definitely worth a look.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, parallelizing do loops is not always as trivial as in the test example Laurence_jj posted. I can imagine the actual code inside the do-loop is way more complex than just a simple assignment (which you could do by removing the do loop and replacing it with a simple `outgrid(1:CAPQ)=ingrid(1:CAPQ)` anyway). Depending on what's inside the loop, special care including other OpenMP features might be needed. And it can be even worse: In some cases, a do-loop can't be parallelized at all.